# Who is the voice actor of Shouya's mother in Koe no Katachi (The Shape of Voice) movie?

Tags: voice-acting, koe-no-katachi

As per the title, who is the voice actor/seiyuu of [Shouya's mother](https://myanimelist.net/character/97577/Mother_Ishida) in [Koe no Katachi the movie](https://myanimelist.net/anime/28851/Koe_no_Katachi)? It will be great if the source of the answer is stated too.

Comment: Side note: I have a feeling she's voiced by Kana Hanazawa who had also voiced Mayumi Saegusa in Mahouka Koukou no Rettousei but i can't seem to find any info about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouya's mother, Miyako's CV is [credited](https://matome.naver.jp/m/odai/2138966632041616801) as [ゆきのさつき/雪野五月](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%86%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%95%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8D) (Yukino Satsuki).

Comment: Verified [on the English Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satsuki_Yukino) as well.

Comment: Oh thanks! I know the answer is in some Japanese website! And I guess I can't find any info in the English wiki because I didn't realize her name is Miyako